# HTML5 iframe sandbox attribute -- downloading but not executing scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I'm hoping to use an iframe to pre-cache some javascript scripts in the browser, but I don't want these scripts to execute. My current approach is:

#### iframe.htm

`<script src="foobar.js"></script>`

#### parent.htm

`<iframe src="iframe.htm" sandbox></iframe>`

This blocks execution of the script, and in chrome at least, it also downloads the script, which is exactly the behavior that I want.

My question is -- is this behavior guaranteed as part of the html5 spec, or tomorrow could browsers change to stop the download as well as the execution?

Comment: There is no guarantee of any kind for the future, but I don't think this will be changing in a few years. Definitely not tomorrow :-). By the way, does this really "block execution"? It actually executes it in the frame.

Comment: Yes, `sandbox` does block scripts by default: `iframe.htm:1 Blocked script execution in 'file:///Users/me/iframe.htm' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.`

Comment: I know, I know. Otherwise I wouldn't be answering your question if I didn't know. It was a joke because I started with **There is no guarantee ... for the future**, then said **in a few years**, then said **not tomorrow**, so the joke was something like **it is not working even today**. Of course, you know that the older browsers don't support it, so the joke is about what you will hear from those using older browsers **the execution is not blocked... it executes it in the frame**.. But jokes aside, my answer still stands **I don't think this will be changing in a few years**.